# Application of the Hoelder inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, inequality

How to prove using Hoelder Inequality that,
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E} (O (|X_i| + |X_i|^3 )) \leq 
n \, \mathbb{E} (O ( |X|^3 ) ),$$
where $X = (X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n)$ are i.i.d. independent random variables with $0$ expectation and unit variance? In the previous expression we have the expectation of a term of the order $O( \, \cdot \, )$ and $| \, \cdot \, |$ denotes the Eucledian norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use Holder with $p=3$

2) Use Jensen to get $E(|X|^{3/2})^{2/3}  \le E(|X|^2)^k$ for some $k$, $rhs = 1$ anyway.

This gives 
$E|X| \leq 
 \mathbb{E} (O ( |X|^3 ) )^{1/3}$ and we know by Jensen $E(|X|^2) = 1 \le E(|X|^3)^{2/3}  $, therefore $E(|X|^3) \ge 1$. This finally gives $E|X| \le \mathbb{E} |X|^3  $